# how to divide repeating patterns in regex?

Tags: java, regex

imagine there is a line of string like this:

`"  jack   for { 123 for{}} rose for {}"`

i want to divide it and get these two lines as output:

```
jack   for { 123 for{}}   
rose for {}
```

the following regex pattern does not solve the problem and i don't now where to put the greedy quantifier:
`[\S\s]*(for)\s*\{[\S\s]*}`

any kind of help would really really be appreciated

Comment: on what basis are you dividing the string?

Comment: `(?<=}) ` would work for the example provided assuming you are simply using the `.split()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using regex for that task and implement a simple parser instead :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("  jack   for { 123 for{}} rose for {}");
sc.useDelimiter("");
List<String> resultingParts = new ArrayList<>();
int currentNestingDepth=0;
StringBuilder currentPart= new StringBuilder();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
    if (c == '{') { currentNestingDepth++; }
    else if (c == '}') {
        currentNestingDepth--; //!\\ might fail with unbalanced parens, test > 0 if needed

        if (currentNestingDepth == 0) { //we've reached the end of a part
            currentPart.append(c);
            resultingParts.add(currentPart.toString());
            currentPart = new StringBuilder();
            continue; // to avoid adding the current character yet again
        }
    }
   currentPart.append(c);
}
if (currentPart.length() > 0) { resultingParts.add(currentPart.toString()); }
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/8uP6Ef).

Comment: I thought regex would be the only solution to my problem, but you prove me wrong. You are a lifesaver, thank you so much.

Comment: @AliNorouzi you're welcome ! As a rule of thumb if you need context (e.g. "Is that `}` I'm reading closing a top-level `{}` or a nested one?") regex isn't the appropriate tool

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that outside names are always "words" and inner string are always numbers a feasible regexp would be:

```
\s*\w+\s*for\s*\{(\s*\d+\s*for\s*\{.*\})*\}
```

https://regex101.com/r/V3MNFd/1